# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Именно поэтому при подготовке дизайн-проекта квартиры в Иваново в качестве отопления был выбран "Blablabla"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая после фразы "Именно поэтому при подготовке дизайн-проекта квартиры в Иваново..." в предложении ниже? И почему да/нет?

**Именно поэтому при подготовке дизайн-проекта квартиры в Иваново в качестве отопления был выбран "Blablabla".**

Answer (score 3):

Можно попробовать проще, чем предлагает Sibylla:

попробуйте "выбросить" из структуры предложения "необязательные" слова - дополнения, определения, - и получим:

*при подготовке дизайн-проекта в качестве отопления был выбран "Blablabla"* -

нам сразу расхочется ставить где бы то ни было запятые.

О. И даже необязательно при подготовке чего и в качестве чего этот "Blablabla": *при подготовке был выбран*.

Тогда ещё одно "о". Так Вас интересует, не является ли вводным предлог "при" <подготовке>? Не-а.

Но:

> Обстоятельственные члены предложения, имеющие в своем составе
>   производные предлоги и предложные сочетания (благодаря, вопреки,
>   ввиду, в целях, в связи с, во избежание, вследствие, по случаю, по
>   причине, при наличии, согласно с, в отличие от, в противоположность,
>   наподобие, при условии, в силу, за отсутствием, несмотря на, невзирая
>   на, спустя, независимо от и др.), обособляются при подчеркивании их
>   смысла.

Answer (score 2):

Именно поэтому //при подготовке дизайн-проекта квартиры в Иваново// в качестве отопления был выбран "Blablabla".

Оборот **с обстоятельственным значением не обособляется,** так как входит в основное сообщение, а не является уточняющим.

Предложение является распространенным, поэтому в нем присутствуют произносительные паузы между группами слов, но эти паузы не обозначаются запятой, так как **не имеют грамматического значения.**